# adding rows and columns together using flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

i am trying to add two-row and 4 columns, I added rows but couldn't add columns, I want them to take the same size so I used expanded()
here is a picture [image]

here is what iam lokking for [image]

i am done with rows but couldn't adds columns

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return MaterialApp(
  home: Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      title: Text("homepage"),
    ),
    backgroundColor: Colors.yellowAccent[700],
    body: SafeArea(
      child: Row(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.yellowAccent[700],
              child: ClipRRect(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20), // Image border
                child: SizedBox.fromSize(
                  size: Size.fromRadius(75), // Image radius
                  child: Image.network('https://picsum.photos/250?image=9',
                      fit: BoxFit.cover),
                ),
              ),
              margin: EdgeInsets.all(15),
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.yellowAccent[700],
              child: ClipRRect(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20), // Image border
                child: SizedBox.fromSize(
                  size: Size.fromRadius(75), // Image radius
                  child: Image.network('https://picsum.photos/250?image=9',
                      fit: BoxFit.cover),
                ),
              ),
              margin: EdgeInsets.all(15),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      
    ),
  ),
);
```

Comment: Can you include an image that you are trying to design, i think it not just about row in future.

Comment: can i navigate from each image if i used gridview?

Comment: yes , you can, wrap item  with `GestureDetector` or `Inkwell`.

Comment: ok is that possible to use column and row with expanded and container without gridview

Comment: i updated my design

Comment: yes, the UI is two column 4 rows?

Comment: yes i want two rows 4 column

Comment: Can you edit  question and check update answer

Comment: Image provider: NetworkImage("https://picsum.photos/250?image=9", scale: 1.0)
Image key: NetworkImage("https://picsum.photos/250?image=9", scale: 1.0)
 i get these error

Comment: Which answer you've tested? Can you clarify

Comment: second one using rows and columns

Comment: oh its work i think the problem is my network

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `GridView`.

```dart
 GridView.count(
  crossAxisCount: 2,
  crossAxisSpacing: 10,
  mainAxisSpacing: 10,
  children: [
    ...List.generate(
      6,
      (index) => ClipRRect(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20), // Image border
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.yellowAccent[700],
          child: SizedBox.fromSize(
            size: Size.fromRadius(75), // Image radius
            child: Image.network(
                'https://picsum.photos/250?image=9',
                fit: BoxFit.cover),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    )
  ],
),
```

Using Row and Column, you need to provide fixed height for each Row.

```dart
    body: SafeArea(
          child: LayoutBuilder(
            builder: (context, constraints) => Column(
              children: [
                SizedBox(
                  height: constraints.maxHeight * .3,
                  child: Row(
                    children: [
                      ...List.generate(
                        2,
                        (index) => Expanded(
                          child: Container(
                            color: Colors.yellowAccent[700],
                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(12),
                            child: ClipRRect(
                              borderRadius:
                                  BorderRadius.circular(20), // Image border
                              child: Image.network(
                                  'https://picsum.photos/250?image=9',
                                  fit: BoxFit.cover),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: constraints.maxHeight * .3,
                  child: Row(
                    children: [
                      ...List.generate(
                        2,
                        (index) => Expanded(
                          child: Container(
                            color: Colors.yellowAccent[700],
                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(12),
                            child: ClipRRect(
                              borderRadius:
                                  BorderRadius.circular(20), // Image border
                              child: Image.network(
                                  'https://picsum.photos/250?image=9',
                                  fit: BoxFit.cover),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
```

Answer (score 0):

```
return MaterialApp(
  home: Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      title: Text("homepage"),
    ),
    backgroundColor: Colors.yellowAccent[700],
    body: SafeArea(
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: [
          Column(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: Container(
                  color: Colors.yellowAccent[700],
                  child: ClipRRect(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20), // Image border
                    child: SizedBox.fromSize(
                      size: Size.fromRadius(size), // Image radius
                      child: Image.network(
                          'https://picsum.photos/250?image=9' ,
                          fit: BoxFit.cover),
                    ),
                  ),
                  margin: EdgeInsets.all(margin),
                ),
              ),
Expanded(
                child: Container(
                  color: Colors.yellowAccent[700],
                  child: ClipRRect(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20), // Image border
                    child: SizedBox.fromSize(
                      size: Size.fromRadius(size), // Image radius
                      child: Image.network(
                          'https://picsum.photos/250?image=9',
                          fit: BoxFit.cover),
                    ),
                  ),
                  margin: EdgeInsets.all(margin),
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: Container(
                  color: Colors.yellowAccent[700],
                  child: ClipRRect(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20), // Image border
                    child: SizedBox.fromSize(
                      size: Size.fromRadius(size), // Image radius
                      child: Image.network(
                          'https://picsum.photos/250?image=9',
                          fit: BoxFit.cover),
                    ),
                  ),
                  margin: EdgeInsets.all(margin),
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: Container(
                  color: Colors.yellowAccent[700],
                  child: ClipRRect(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20), // Image border
                    child: SizedBox.fromSize(
                      size: Size.fromRadius(size), // Image radius
                      child: Image.network(
                          'https://picsum.photos/250?image=9',
                          fit: BoxFit.cover),
                    ),
                  ),
                  margin: EdgeInsets.all(margin),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
Column(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: Container(
                  color: Colors.yellowAccent[700],
                  child: ClipRRect(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20), // Image border
                    child: SizedBox.fromSize(
                      size: Size.fromRadius(size), // Image radius
                      child: Image.network(
                          'https://picsum.photos/250?image=9',
                          fit: BoxFit.cover),
                    ),
                  ),
                  margin: EdgeInsets.all(margin),
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: Container(
                  color: Colors.yellowAccent[700],
                  child: ClipRRect(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20), // Image border
                    child: SizedBox.fromSize(
                      size: Size.fromRadius(size), // Image radius
                      child: Image.network(
                          'https://picsum.photos/250?image=9',
                          fit: BoxFit.cover),
                    ),
                  ),
                  margin: EdgeInsets.all(margin),
                ),
              ),
Expanded(
                child: Container(
                  color: Colors.yellowAccent[700],
                  child: ClipRRect(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20), // Image border
                    child: SizedBox.fromSize(
                      size: Size.fromRadius(size), // Image radius
                      child: Image.network(
                          'https://picsum.photos/250?image=9',
                          fit: BoxFit.cover),
                    ),
                  ),
                  margin: EdgeInsets.all(margin),
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: Container(
                  color: Colors.yellowAccent[700],
                  child: ClipRRect(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20), // Image border
                    child: SizedBox.fromSize(
                      size: Size.fromRadius(size), // Image radius
                      child: Image.network(
                          'https://t3.ftcdn.net/jpg/04/33/08/02/360_F_433080252_BWd42il6gVUmQaXIkASbUrHfKMV3fnqg.jpg',
                          fit: BoxFit.cover),
                    ),
                  ),
                  margin: EdgeInsets.all(margin),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
);


}
}
```

this is the answer [image]

I just added a column inside a row with expanded so it take the same size

Comment: Code is a lot more helpful when it is accompanied by an explanation. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please [edit] your question and explain how it answers the specific question being asked. See [answer].